# crystal report error: "a string is required here" on select

Tags: crystal-reports

I run the following code in crystal reports and it tells me that

> " string is required here"

on the second case.  I've tried casting {?Pm-Student_course_attendance_csv.Level} as a string, but no luck

```
 Global NumberVar grade;
 Global NumberVar baseline;

Select ({?Pm-Student_course_attendance_csv.Level})
  Case "R", "TL", "TU", "OTH", "P", "BTECFS": 
    If (CStr({PM_csv.mv_value}) = "Pass") Then
       "On Track"
    Else
       "Below"

  Case "H", "ASD", "AD", "AS", "G":     //error from this line onwards inclusive
     Select (CStr({PM_csv.mv_value}))
        Case "A*":
            grade := 11
        Case "A*/A":
            grade := 10
        Case "A":
            grade := 9
        Case "A/B":
            grade := 8
        Case "B":
            grade := 7
        Case "B/C":
            grade := 6
        Case "C":
            grade := 5
        Case "C/D":
            grade := 4
        Case "D":
            grade := 3
        Case "D/E":
            grade := 2
        Case "E":
            grade := 1
        Case "U":
            grade := 0
        Default :
            grade := 0;
```

Comment: What types are your fields? (Parameter {?Pm-Student_course_attendance_csv.Level} and what looks like db field {PM_csv.mv_value})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula cannot have two different return types. From the error and above it returns a string, but below it you are trying to return a number (A formula's return type is also the last assignment, so if the last thing your formula does is `grade:=1` then the formula tries to return the value 1, which it obviously won't allow you to do. You have to add a string return value for each case in the second half of the formula.

```
...
  Case "H", "ASD", "AD", "AS", "G":     //error from this line onwards inclusive
     Select (CStr({PM_csv.mv_value}))
        Case "A*":
            grade := 11;
            "Return value" //<---- Must be a string
        Case "A*/A":
...
```