# Crystal Report Parameter Date format not support?

Tags: crystal-reports

When I run/edit the report I have some error which Date format like this:

[image: Crystal Report Date Error.]

Follow up suggestion lead to the next issue:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [crystal report error: "a string is required here" on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313162/crystal-report-error-a-string-is-required-here-on-select)

Comment: But i have some column type date from my table. When i Expert Database this field automatic change from date to string. What should i do ?

Comment: Your comment `When i Expert Database this field automatic change from date to string` is not clear to me? Why is the datatype being changed?....You can't compare a string and a date. So, in short, you have to either prevent the date from being converted to a string, or convert the string to a date in the selectionformula.

Comment: When i run this report will show up following.
1. https://i.imgur.com/Qr8FuPl.png
2. https://i.imgur.com/zcF1lSh.png